# Downloading file works on PC but can only get 16kb on Android

Tags: java, android, url, download

I have been trying to get this for ages now. The exact code works perfectly when executed as just straight Java but when used in Android it only downloads 16kbs max before stopping. I just have no idea why.

The code is:

```
URL website = new URL(url);
URLConnection connection = website.openConnection();
connection.connect();
int fileSize = connection.getContentLength();
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Initializer.getPath(saveName));
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, fileSize);//using filesize = very large number has no effect except eventual out of memory issues.
```

The above downloads pdf's correctly for pdf's of size less than 16kb but just stops at this size for all pdf's. And like I said, in a non-Android environment this works 100%.

I have also tried this:

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
            File f = new File(Initializer.getPath(saveName));
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));

            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                bw.write(line);
                bw.newLine();
            }
            br.close();
            bw.close();
```

Which gives me files of size greater than 16kb but these are just blank.

An example url that fails:

```
"https://www.uct.ac.za/downloads/uct.ac.za/currentstud/services/jammie/term/10_hiddingh_weekwkndph.pdf"
```

Example that works (due to it's size):

```
"https://www.uct.ac.za/downloads/uct.ac.za/currentstud/services/jammie/vac/10_hiddingh.pdf"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wondering (without testing) if the BufferedReader allocating its internal buffer of 8192 bytes and fails on the 3rd go-round because of a timeout or some other issue. The following code reads a byte at a time from the BufferedInputStream and works well for me on Android. Can you give this a try to see if it resolves the issue?

```
    try {
    //URL u  = new URL("https://www.uct.ac.za/downloads/uct.ac.za/currentstud/services/jammie/term/10_hiddingh_weekwkndph.pdf");
    URL u  = new URL("https://www.uct.ac.za/downloads/uct.ac.za/currentstud/services/jammie/vac/10_hiddingh.pdf");

    HttpsURLConnection connection;

    connection = (HttpsURLConnection)u.openConnection();
    BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int byte_read = is.read();
    while(byte_read != -1)
    {
        bos.write(byte_read);
        byte_read = is.read();
    }

    byte[] bos_data = bos.toByteArray();
    System.out.println("buffer data length " + bos_data.length);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: It looks like internally BufferedReader just clears out the buffer of 8192 bytes. You're only making it through two loops of the private fill() method. Not sure why, but probably a timeout.

Comment: Hi thanks for the attempt. I tried to write this to a file with a FileOutputStream and then, just to try, a BufferedWrtier. Both gave files that where very small (0.3kb) in size as a result. I thought about the timeout as an issue, do you know how to set this to something high?

Comment: I've just created an Eclipse project and I'm testing it out. I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: Well, when I run it in Eclipse in the emulated environment, it works fine. Both files download completely. 21677 bytes for one, and 15701 for the other, smaller file. Note however that I edited my code. It used to say while(byte_read > 0) which was incorrect. It is now correct and downloads the file without issue. Could you give it a try?

Comment: Thanks this works! So it was that the buffer is being cleared? And just a note, this works for URLConnection as well.

Comment: Glad it works. I think it's rather that when you construct a BufferedReader without specifying the buffer size, it creates a default buffer of 8192 bytes. Instead of resizing or creating a new one, it simply empties the buffer. Since you were getting files of 16k (hint: 8192 + 8192), it appears the buffer is not refilling. OR, since you're using the readLine() function, there is no end of line at the end of the buffer. Without more testing and looking at the files themselves, I don't know what the exact problem is.

Comment: Same story with the ReadableByteChannel attempt? Anyway, thanks again, I appreciate the time you took to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code to solve this problem :

```
public void DownloadFromUrl(String DownloadUrl, String fileName) {
  try {
       File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();  
       File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/xmls");
       if(dir.exists()==false) {
            dir.mkdirs();
       }

       URL url = new URL(DownloadUrl); //you can write here any link
       File file = new File(dir, fileName);

       long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
       Log.d("DownloadManager", "download url:" + url);

       /* Open a connection to that URL. */
       URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

       /*
        * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
        */
       InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
       BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

       /*
        * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
        */
       ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(5000);
       int current = 0;
       while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
          baf.append((byte) current);
       }

       /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
       FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
       fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
       fos.flush();
       fos.close();
       Log.d("DownloadManager", "download ready in" + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000) + " sec");
  } catch (IOException e) {
   Log.d("DownloadManager", "Error: " + e);
  }
 }
```